# Solcx compile source erroe

Tags: import, compiler-errors, compilation, solidity

Exception has occurred: SolcNotInstalled
solc 0.6.0 has not been installed. Use solcx.install_solc('0.6.0') to install.
File "C:\Users\gilld\Documents\Demos\vstoolbox\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 8, in 
compiled_sol = compile_standard(

Answer (score 0):

you need to install solidity compiler you can install it through this website

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc
```

Comment: from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json

install_solc("0.6.0")


with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

Comment: I thought it was using this line of code above and version is ticked in settings. Still having this syntax error message.